# Can Squish It publish files to a CDN

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cdn, web-farm, squishit

I just found squish it, it looks very promising but I need to upload my js and css scripts to our CDN servers. We have 10 web servers and an external CDN.

Is there a way to upload the compressed files to a CDN or does it only work on a single server.

Comment: There's been some activity in the last few months around supporting CDN scenarios, it may do what you need at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the Yahoo Yui Compressor MsBuildTask on a post build event to compress and combine our javascript and css. Then I created a simple html helper method to detect debug and release mode to write the script tags.